# namespace prefixes with jackson

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, woodstox

So im using Jackson 2.9.3 with Woodstox.

i can define xmlns with this java annotation:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "metadata", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")
public class Metadata {
```

resulting in this on deserialization:

```
<metadata xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">...</metadata>
```

And this is working as intended.

But **how** is it possible to achieve a namespace prefix like this:

```
<metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:title id="title">Recollections of Wartime</dc:title>
```

so there should be a namespace-prefix defined in the root element: **xmlns:dc** = "..."

and child tags/attributes should be able to use that prefix: <**dc**:title>

Is that possible with jackson/woodstox?

Comment: these are both the same dom (despite one does not have prefix, the namespace applied is still the same and after parsing, they are strictly equals one and the other). are you sure your consumer can not understand the 1st xml? he should.

Comment: you are right that this should be understandable, but the project requirements are very clear on that one, so i need to achieve the second result.

Comment: I don't know woodstox, but a quick look at the source shows that the file https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ctc/wstx/sw/BaseNsStreamWriter.java has a variable ```NamespaceContext mRootNsContext``` documented as ```it can be used to lookup namespace/prefix mappings``` so using that you could (I guess) override prefix resolution

Comment: thanks for the hint!